# Are questions about Bluetooth enabled devices allowed on SU?

Tags: discussion

If I'm trying to connect my Wii remote to my computer via Bluetooth, would a question on that be allowed?  I ask, because you might be creating an accessory for your PC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is a very thin line, if the problem connecting is with the computer or the bluetooth device it would be on topic.

> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except **insofar as they interface with your computer**

However, I would not be surprised if the community does decide that it is off topic, or if the question is about configuring the WII specifically, it would get closed.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll make sure that it relates as closely as possible to the computer, and not to the device.